# Resources for real time market intelligence

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, stock-markets, markets

What are the best resources to obtain real time news that have a direct impact on the markets? If Im trying to research in the pre-market hours for the most up-to date information that will move stocks up or down, where should I be looking? There is so much out there Im lost as to what I should focus on for real time news specifically in the pre-market hours. 
Yes, Im a rookie at this:)

Comment: Almost all business websites/channels i.e. Bloomberg, CNBC, FT etc.

Comment: There have been a few questions on this topic before.  See, for example, the second half of [this answer](http://money.stackexchange.com/a/39487/7926).  Also check out some of the other [questions](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stock-analysis) in the tags you chose.

Answer (score 1):

I use to day trade at a Prop Desk over 3 years ago. We used to find "In Play" stocks or stocks with breaking news (i.e. earnings announcements, FDA approval, etc...) using briefing.com or theflyonthewall.com. There are all sorts of different strategies for In Play stocks.